# Need to split 1st string before delimiter which is comma(,)

Tags: shell

Need to split the 1st string before delimiter comma.
For example

```
A="ABC:20.10.0-5,DEF:21.10.0-9,XYZ:20.10.0-9"
```

We need to extract 1st string before the comma(,) and the result should be like this -

```
B="ABC:20.10.0-5"
```

After this, I need to extract the numbers after colon(:) and before the dash(-). So the final value should be -

```
C="20.10.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with simple shell substitution:

```
A="ABC:20.10.0-5,DEF:21.10.0-9,XYZ:20.10.0-9"
B="${A%%,*}" # Remove everything after the first comma and the comma itself
nodash="${B%%-*}" # Remove everything after the dash and the dash itself
C="${nodash##*:}" # Remove everything before the colon and the colon itself
```

Comment: oops i forgot to keep the intermediate value of B accurate, fixing it

Comment: but this doesn't print double quotes or the capitalized alphabet with assignment operator

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below code. I wasn't sure where exactly are you running it as there's only one tag and also that if you actually wanted to print double quotes in the output. Hence, i added them as well. I am assuming you are aware of `cut` command.

```
-bash-4.2$ cat test2.sh 
#!/bin/bash

A="ABC:20.10.0-5,DEF:21.10.0-9,XYZ:20.10.0-9"
echo "A="\"$A\"
B=`echo $A | cut -d"," -f1`
echo "B="\"$B\"
C=`echo $B | cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d"-" -f1`
echo "C="\"$C\"

-bash-4.2$ ./test2.sh 
A="ABC:20.10.0-5,DEF:21.10.0-9,XYZ:20.10.0-9"
B="ABC:20.10.0-5"
C="20.10.0"
```